# Одинаковые члены в ограниченном и неограниченном перечислениях

Tags: c++, enum, c++20

```
enum UnscopedColor { red, green, blue };
enum class ScopedColor { red, green, blue };

int main() {
  using enum ScopedColor;
}
```

Какой из енумов будет использоваться и почему так? Как использовать определённый?

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: @Духсообщества что непонятно?

Comment: @Духсообщества D:

Comment: Ну а вы проверили, что происходит на популярных компилятораз? *"Как использовать определённый?"* Я думаю тут и ежу понятно.

Comment: `ScopedColor::red`

Answer (score 3):

Как известно,

```
enum UnscopedColor { red, green, blue };
```

не только определяет тип `UnscopedColor`, но и добавляет три идентификатора `red`, `green` и `blue` в глобальную область видимости.

Это означает, что в коде мы можем написать `red` и ожидать, что получим значение именно идентификатора `red` из перечисления `UnscopedColor` (т.е. 0). Правда ровно до тех пор, пока кто-нибудь не добавит в локальную область видимости новый идентификатор `red`, который перекроет `red` из глобальной области видимости. Есть много способов это сделать.

Например просто создать переменную с именем `red`:

```
#include <iostream>

enum UnscopedColor { red, green, blue };

int main() {
  std::cout << red << std::endl; // это red = 0 из UnscopedColor
  auto red = 42;
  std::cout << red << std::endl; // а это наша новая локальная переменная red = 42
}
```

Или вытащить идентификатор `red` из каких-то глубин:

```
#include <iostream>

enum UnscopedColor { red, green, blue };

namespace A {
  namespace B {
    constexpr const char red[] = "red";
  }
}

int main() {
  std::cout << red << std::endl; // это red = 0 из UnscopedColor
  using A::B::red;
  std::cout << red << std::endl; // угадай кто здесь
}
```

В целом это достаточно универсальный механизм в C++ когда более новые идентификаторы вводятся в локальную область видимости и перекрывают старые (пока область видимости не закончится).

Тем не менее есть способ (не всегда, но есть) достучаться да скрытых идентификаторов. Например тех, которые объявлены в глобальной области видимости. Достаточно использовать префикс `::`. Т.е. в наших примерах мы можем писать `::red` и быть уверенными, что это будет именно идентификатор из `UnscopedColor`, а не откуда-то еще.

Возвращаясь к оригинальному коду,

```
enum UnscopedColor { red, green, blue };
enum class ScopedColor { red, green, blue };

int main() {
  using enum ScopedColor;
}
```

думаю уже стало понятно какой enum "будет использоваться". Хотя это не совсем корректный вопрос. Т.к. `using enum` ничего не делает с самим типом `ScopedColor`, а только вносит имена `red`, `green` и `blue` типа `ScopedColor` в локальную область видимости (и естественно перекрывает старые идентификаторы из `UnscopedColor`). И если бы в `ScopedColor` отсутствовал `blue`, то в локальной области видимости мы бы получили прекрасный микс: `red` и `green` были бы типа `ScopedColor`, а `blue` принадлежал бы `UnscopedColor`. Ну лучше так не делать разумеется.

Answer (score -1):

В данном случае будет использоваться `enum class ScopedColor`, потому что он объявлен с ключевым словом `class`, что означает, что имена перечислений будут принадлежать области видимости этого перечисления.